# kendo ASP.NET MVC specific multiselect in Gantt Edit

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect, kendo-gantt

I am a new user of kendo and I have a problem with a gantt!
I have a page with a Gantt kendo. For each activity I have a button edit. When my popup edit is open I have lot of fields and a multiselect. This multiselect should be specific for each activity.

I have put the code below in my function edit Gantt :

```js
$.get('/Activity/ReadMultiSelectActivities?initiativeId=' + @Model.ID + '&excludeSectorId=' + $('#SectorID').val() + "&activityID=" + e.task.id, function (data, status) {
  allActivitiesDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: data.Data,
    group: { field: "SectorName" },
    sort: { field: "ActivityNumberString", dir: "asc" }
  });
});
var msLinkedActivities = $('#linkedActivities').data('kendoMultiSelect');
msLinkedActivities.setDataSource(allActivitiesDataSource);
```

My problem is that I get the impression that my code is read into account with a delay time. That is, if I click on edit activity 1 the first time the list is empty, I close the edit and then return to edit activity 1 the list is filled. If then I go on edit activity 2 it will be the list of activity 1 ...

I tried many things that I view on tuto, demo and forum telerik but nothings function!

Have you an Idea for fix this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

For information I have resolve my probelm. This is because the data are long to retrieve and so it made the setDataSource before loading the data!